# ubuntu 20.04 LTS can't Hide grub menu

Tags: boot, grub2, startup, 20.04

I have recently upgraded to ubuntu 20.04 LTS, it works charmingly but all I want is to hide grub menu on booting. Yes, I tried to edit `/etc/default/grub`. Timeout is set to 0 sec in default, and I'm still seeing the grub menu on startup with timeout 30 sec.

I tried to edit using grub-customizer and no luck

[image: Startup screen]

timeout is showing 30 secs

Comment: Can you also post screenshots of grub customizer and /etc/default/grub. Is the show menu ticked off in General setting in grub customizer? @Umesh Eswaran

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GRUB\_TIMEOUT in /etc/default/grub not changing the wait time with LVM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1123290/grub-timeout-in-etc-default-grub-not-changing-the-wait-time-with-lvm)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using lvm or btrfs for your `/` partition.

This is made by design, because `grub` can't write to either of those. This may lead to unablity to enter `grub` after a boot failure.

If you are sure that's not a problem for you, add `GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=0` to `/etc/default/grub` and run

```
sudo update-grub
```

Otherwise consider making a separate `/boot` partition formatted to `ext2`.

Comment: what does GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=0 do?

Comment: It sets 0 timeout for system with boot on `lvm` or `btrfs`. Recordfail means that grub can't write to `/boot`. Without this line, timeout is set to 30.

Comment: It Worked but on startup im getting this message "initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed"

Comment: It is unrelated.

Comment: work perfecly on elementary os 6.1 jolnir (base ubuntu 20.04)

Comment: Wow, this setting I applied 2 years ago came back to bite me today: after upgrading to 23.04, I wasn’t able to boot (due to some issue with Nvidia drivers), and indeed, I was completely unable to enter grub (with shift/escape/space/whatnot) and launch Ubuntu in recovery mode. I had to use a liveusb to fix my setup… I will keep a value of 2 seconds instead now.

Answer (score -1):

**Try changing grub settings,**

Start termina(Ctrl + Alt + T)and type in terminal:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Change GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=false to

> GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true

Save and exit

After that type in terminal:

```
sudo update-grub
```