# Grub timeout of 30s cannot be modified or disabled

Tags: boot, grub2, timeout

Running Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.
On boot I get a grub menu with 2 entries (Ubuntu and Advanced) and a timeout of 30s. I want to either disable the timeout, either reduce the time to a few seconds.

This is my /etc/default/grub file, but timeout is still 30s:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub'     afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT="saved"
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="countdown"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="2"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="maybe-ubiquity"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL="console"

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE="640x480"

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID="true"

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT="5"

#GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER="false"

#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT="1"
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT="true"
```

The entire /boot/grub/grub.cfg can be found here https://pastebin.com/qT6rFTvM

Comment: Did you run `sudo update-grub` after updating this file?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli Yes, I did.

Comment: Can you check that your timeout value ("2") is reflected in the file: `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` by using this command: `grep -i timeout /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

Comment: output of that grep is:
https://pastebin.com/JU5z1R0S

Comment: @FedonKadifeli Thank you for the suggestion. I also added the entire content of grub.cfg in the initial description.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ubuntu 20.04 LTS can't Hide grub menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1236136/ubuntu-20-04-lts-cant-hide-grub-menu)

Comment: @Pilot6 I just tried both answers, one at a time, and still no change. I have the 30s timeout.

Comment: @Pilot6, but my / partition is indeed LVM, I beleive. Output of df -hT is 
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv ext4      146G   23G  117G  17% /

Comment: If it doesn't work for you, it means that you did something wrong. What is your `/etc/default/grub` now?

Comment: @Pilot6 this is the /etc/defaut/grub: https://pastebin.com/daUc1J9J and this is /boot/grub/grub/cfg https://pastebin.com/ZnSmjUTj

Comment: You've change a lot in `/etc/default/grub`. I would set it to default and then add the RECORDFAIL entry and it should work.

Comment: @Pilot6 I cleared it up and used only this https://pastebin.com/zkseDysu. I tried setting GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT to both 0 and 1. Still not working. If you have any other suggestion, please tell me. I am grateful for your time.

Comment: It works for me. I have no more ideas. Another way is to make a separate `/boot` partition without lvm.