# Two grubs on one install of Ubuntu?

Tags: grub2, bootloader, grub-efi

I recently installed ubuntu 22.04 on a new Intel NUC.  I created a Fat32 boot partition, and a pv for an LVM with mount points for root, etc, usr...et al.  The install went fine and the machine boots.  However, there appears to be two bootloaders.  I don't know if that's an issue for how the machine works, but I can only modify one of the bootloaders to get rid of the timeout (appears to be the second one).  When I look in EFI directory, I see a folder for ubuntu and one for boot - both have boot files in them, but only the ubuntu folder has grub.cfg.  I hope this is making sense.  Should I remove one of the bootloaders?  If not, how do I make the timeouts on both of them zero?  If reloading the OS is the answer, that's fine - I don't have a lot on the machine yet, but need to know how to do that without making the same mistake.

EDIT:  As requested, output of efibootmgr -v

```
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0000
Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,5871a315-fc5c-4a07-aff3-9c3a34ecc50b,0x800,0x200000)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI)
```

and output of lsblk -f | grep -v loop

```
NAME            FSTYPE      FSVER    LABEL UUID                                   FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS
nvme0n1                                                                                          
├─nvme0n1p1     vfat        FAT32          1544-60B4                              1016.7M     1% /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2     swap        1              4f25509f-f6ef-4813-ad42-1e432aecaac0                  [SWAP]
└─nvme0n1p3     LVM2_member LVM2 001       hvwQkX-ARTx-puSH-ZUay-hHhB-HwYk-hMoPYa                
  ├─devlvm-root ext4        1.0            f5cf38fb-64ae-442f-9216-fb8fc34be577     29.2G     1% /
  ├─devlvm-home ext4        1.0            64c19ad2-da7e-4e8a-9687-1e0a856328a4     46.5G    20% /home
  ├─devlvm-opt  ext4        1.0            147239ac-2d64-4a6d-8aae-994f299040ca     59.2G     0% /opt
  ├─devlvm-var  ext4        1.0            f54e47d1-9f48-4b9a-afce-5fbb8f1de029       52G    12% /var
  ├─devlvm-srv  ext4        1.0            bf024629-befc-44dd-8fd9-10a667ad514d     59.2G     0% /srv
  └─devlvm-usr  ext4        1.0            66f9426e-a4eb-4f65-8cc9-7e024a8a60c1     52.1G    11% /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
                                                                                                 /usr
```

Comment: You shouldn't do anything about it. When you install grub, always additional instances of grub will be installed in `/boot/efi/EFI/BOOT` and `/boot/efi/EFI/grub`, at least tthis is the case on my sytem. Reinstalling would therefor not help. the important thing is the boot-order in your UEFI-settings, use the correct instance ( the one in `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu`) as the first entry, the other entries can be used as fallback in case this on is broken.

Comment: Thank you for replying.  How do I modify the UEFI settings?  When I go to the UEFI menu in grub and hit enter, it just reboots the computer to a blank screen.  Feels like something isn't right...

Comment: Please add the output of the commands `efibootmgr -v` and `lsblk -f | grep -v loop` via [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1438542/edit) to your question.

Comment: I see only one EFI-boot-menu entry which is the correct one. No reason to change anything in UEFI-settings. The timeout you experience occurs  most likely due to the fact that `/boot` is inside your LVM and not a dedicated partition.  You can try to add the line `GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=0` to the file `/etc/default/grub`and run `sudo update-grub` after doing that. Reboot to see if it helps.

Comment: I really appreciate your help.  I followed the steps you outlined but no change.  I guess I need to research how to move my boot drive out of the LVM and into its own partition.  I really hate the timeout.....

Comment: [Related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1279680/grub-timeout-of-30s-cannot-be-modified-or-disabled).