# how do I stop this GRUB option to show up when I start my PC

Tags: 20.04, grub-efi

How do I remove this GRUB os selection ?

[image]

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: Probably you have [this Problem](https://askubuntu.com/q/1236136/590937).

Answer (score 0):

You may edit the grub configuration file using the command

```
 sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

and change the line **GRUB_TIMEOUT = 10** to **GRUB_TIMEOUT=0.**  Also add the lines **GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true**
**GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden**

Save the file.
Update the Grub using the command

```
sudo update-grub
```

and reboot the machine.

Comment: It did not work. My grub_timeout was already 0. and added the extra line too. still the screen is showing

Comment: Don't you have to `update-grub` after modifying `/etc/default/grub`?

Comment: @danzel I dont know. if so, how do I do that?

Comment: @yaa__ just run `sudo update-grub` in a terminal.

Comment: @danzel I did all these but still the screen showing. any reason you know why it is not working??

Comment: @yaa_ I've made changes in the answer.