# time out in grub doesn't work properly

Tags: boot, grub2

I have this in my grub setting

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=UUID=7e7b14ea-9a18-42f9-ba6c-d62581e038a9"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

but the time out during boot time is 30 sec.

What is wrong with this setting?

Note: I DID use the following command to update-grub

```
sudo update-grub
```

I also run this command in case it helps but no success.

```
Sudo update-grub2
```

I am using Ubuntu 20.04

## Update 1

```
grep -i timeout /boot/grub/grub.cfg
  set timeout=30
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=menu
    set timeout=10
  # Fallback normal timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
    set timeout=10
```

so the cfg is correct but the timeout is still 30 sec. What this line is doing? I think this line return false and hence the timeout is 30 sec.

```
if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
```

Comment: Does the answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1123290/590937) hit the point?

Comment: No, it is not `if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then` because the `else` sets it also. For whatever reason the previous `if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then` conditional result must be different between our two setups. Mine is just grub with no `lvm` no `efi` ...

Comment: How can I check if I am using lvm or efi? I installed the Linux from scratch on this device recently.

Comment: just try the suggestion in the question/answer linked to above. my `/boot/grub/grub/cfg` file doesn't look anything like the one presented in the answer.

Comment: Remind that the output provided comes from `grep`, so that's not the complete `grub.cfg` You'd rather open `grub.cfg` in your text editor and use it's "find" feature to examine the places where you get matches.